# Mental hospital records for 1939-41 in San Jose, California

Tags: records, california, medicine

I am writing a memoir and want to know more about my maternal grandmother's last years. She was interned at Agnews State Mental Hospital in San Jose, which closed in 1971. I'd like to know exactly when she was sent there, what the diagnosis may have been, and what is said to be her cause of death (I think the dates are 1939-41). I have been unable to find any archival records; there is a bit of a vicious circle involved...You go to a blog on Agnews (courtesy of San Jose library) and it sends you to Patient Records FAQ, but that tells you to go to list of hospitals and the list is short & doesn't include Agnews.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to what to do next? I do have the exact date of death.

- San Jose Public Library: [Looking Back: Agnews State Hospital](https://www.sjpl.org/blogs/post/looking-back-agnews-state-hospital/)
- [State Hospitals - Patient Information Requests - FAQ](https://www.dsh.ca.gov/Hospitals/Patient_Information_Requests_FAQs.html)

Comment: Hi Marilyn, welcome. Do you have a copy of her death certificate? That would be a starting place to confirm date and place of death, and hopefully should also record her cause of death.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  Take a look at this question and see if any of the information helps. https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/9545/1006 In the Patient FAQ I found (see links added to your Q) Agnews is listed in the table with closed facilites and the records are held by the Department of Developmental Services. The names are not in alphabetical order so it is easy to miss a facility in the table.